# Composer: Error when requiring a local repository that requires a local repository

Tags: git, composer-php

I have three projects in my local filesystem that are managed with git, looking something like this:

```
. [project_root]
├── base
│   ├── .git
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── composer.lock
│   ├── src
│   └── vendor
├── dependent
│   ├── .git
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── composer.lock
│   ├── src
│   └── vendor
└── very-dependent
    ├── .git
    ├── composer.json
    ├── composer.lock
    ├── src
    └── vendor
```

`very-dependent` requires both `dependent` and `base`, and `dependent` requires `base`. All depend on the `master` branch of their dependencies.

I've added the repositories accordingly: `dependent` has a `url: "[project_root]/base"` repository reference, and `very-dependent` a `url: "[project_root]/dependent"` reference. When installing/updating in `dependent`, there are no problems. However, installing/updating in `very-dependent`, I'm getting this error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for `local/very-dependent dev-master` -> satisfiable by `local/dependent[dev-master]`.
> - `local/dependent dev-master` requires `local/base dev-master` -> no matching package found.

Any ideas why?

Comment: This sounds like more of a dependency issue than having to do with Git.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Very plausible. Is the `git` tag inappropriate? I thought I would cover my bases in case it was important.

Comment: I'm not sure that Git is relevant here.  But I am only familiar with Java build tools like Maven and Gradle, so I can't help here.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out [it's a conscious design decision of the Composer developers](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md) not to resolve repositories recursively.